# typeorm save in joined cloumn

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

in my project i have two entity, naturalist(user) and comment entity
i create relation between them, how to save reciever_id (joined cloumn) in comment entity

this is my comment entity

```
@Entity()
export class Comments extends BaseEntity {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: string

@ManyToOne(
type => Naturalist,
naturalist => naturalist.comments
)
@JoinColumn({
name: 'naturalist_id',
})
naturalist: Naturalist


@Column({ nullable: true, default: '' })
text?: string

@Column({ nullable: true, default: '' })
sender_id?: string
}
```

naturalist(my user) entity

```
@Entity()
export class Naturalist extends BaseEntity {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number

@Column()
user_id: string


@OneToMany(
type => Comments,
comment => comment.naturalist
)
comments: Comments[]

}
```

DTO contains

```
{
receiver_id: '2cc2f359-821c-4940-99ae-7386576d861b',
text: 'string',
id: 'e0464049-d1d9-474a-af5b-815805aa1c4b'
}
```

i want to save receiver_id to my comment entity

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly your needs,
I think you need an insert method to do this:

```
await entityManager.insert(Comments, { naturalist: { id: '2cc2f359-821c-4940-99ae-7386576d861b' } as Naturalist });
```